# How can I get categories IDs if multiple categories requested via URI?

Tags: categories, templates

Let's say, I have two categories, '`color`' and '`temperature`'. Each one has a number of sub-categories.

Wordpress does great job displaying posts in requested categories when I go to URL like this one:

```
http://www.example.com/category/pink+warm
```

How can I get these categories (IDs or slugs) in category template?

**UPDATE**: Thanks to Rarst; I will analyze `$wp_query->tax_query->queries`.

ps. btw, `http://www.example.com/category/blue,yellow` gives posts in any of `blue` OR `yellow` categories. Nice ,)

pps. AND there may be more than two categories, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm hm. WordPress might be good at making this work, but isn't too good at making it convenient to work *with*. Typically `get_queried_object()` is a good way to access such context, but in this case it will merely hold the *first* term and ignore the rest.

You will probably have to scrape this information out of `$wp_query->tax_query->queries`, which will hold something like this:

```
array(2) [
    array(5) [
        'taxonomy' => string (8) "category"
        'terms' => array(1) [
            string (12) "post-formats"
        ]
        'field' => string (4) "slug"
        'operator' => string (2) "IN"
        'include_children' => bool TRUE
    ]
    array(5) [
        'taxonomy' => string (8) "category"
        'terms' => array(1) [
            string (6) "markup"
        ]
        'field' => string (4) "slug"
        'operator' => string (2) "IN"
        'include_children' => bool TRUE
    ]
]
```

Comment: Yes, I've already played with this a bit; I wish there would be an API call .) I'll accept your answer if there is no better way; I'll wait a bit. Thank you!